# log4j2 causes error - "The method info(Message) is ambiguous for the type Logger"

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, log4j2

Below mentioned method worked fine with SLF4J (org.slf4j.Logger). I replaced SLF4J with LOG4J2.

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

@Test
public void someTestMethod() {
    // Test Class related code. 
    Logger logger = mock(Logger.class);
    verify(logger, times(1)).info(any());
}
```

This test gives compile time error - "The method info(Message) is ambiguous for the type Logger".

Any suggestions on how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this is java compiler tries to find out the method with most specific input parameters to invoke a method.
Method info() takes a string as the specific object, but you are passing Object to it. Pass any string object to it, will resolve your problem.